# wordpress wp-admin css not loading

Tags: wp-admin, admin-css

> previously its have SSL now don't have SSl

my word press admin dashboard css not loading  but home page and other page are working perfect any one know how to fix this?

> no ssl its just http

[image]

already some ask same question here but those answer not solve my problems

[Wordpress wp-admin suddenly lost its style](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217288/wordpress-wp-admin-suddenly-lost-its-style)

[Wordpress Admin Panel Completely Distorted, no css at all](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163802/wordpress-admin-panel-completely-distorted-no-css-at-all)

the same question ask from some other stack exchange network

[Wordpress admin not loading css/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769141/wordpress-admin-not-loading-css-js)

[wordpress login page not getting load-styles.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277410/wordpress-login-page-not-getting-load-styles-php)

[Wordpress wp-admin suddenly lost its style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325159/wordpress-wp-admin-suddenly-lost-its-style)

[WP admin Screen Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197880/wp-admin-screen-issue)

[Wordpress Dashboard Display error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641107/wordpress-dashboard-display-error)

```
the most common answer is 

    define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
 add this line your wp-config,php
```

i try everything still not loading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue a few months back I tried this and this works for me.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

try to load wp-admin with SSL.

After reloading it looks OK, maybe after re-login, set SCRIPT_DEBUG to false.

hope this help

Comment: https://ibb.co/0rbLW3f   https://ibb.co/4TBCkDj  afre edit wp-admin 404

Comment: adn dont have ssl :)

Comment: `define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);`
`define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);`  i change like this :) really thz dude