# Wordpress Dashboard is loaded without css

Tags: admin-css

Just got a new update from WordPress and installed update from dashboard successfully. Everything was ok after refreshing the page I got dashboard without CSS.

[image: This is how the dashboard is looking after update]

Tried googling and found some solutions for the problem but nothing worked for me.

- `define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
  define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true );`
- `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';`

site is being loaded with https but in the network library,

[image: This is network lib]

[image]
 while inspecting I'm not getting any CSS file, it's completely missing. tried playing with a general setting for URL change but not much luck found.

Let me know what wrong happened by me.

Comment: When you say your CSS doesn't load, what does happen? Is the CSS includes missing completely from the page? Do they load the wrong domain? Do they load `http` but your site is `https`? Do they have the correct URL but 404 when visited? What does the browser dev tools console tell you? Please edit your question using the edit link to provide as much info as you can, even if it's just to say that you don't know or can't find

Comment: @TomJNowell site is being loaded with https but in the network library, while inspecting I'm not getting any CSS file, it's completely missing. tried playing with general setting for URL change but not much luck found .

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure your Wordpress site is listed as the https address. Is it possible that you're forcing an https address but you've left the Wordpress address as http?

If you think that might be the case, perhaps either take off the 'force https' and then update the WP site to the https address in the settings (then you can put the 'force https' back on).

Or, put the correct address in the database. Eg. [edit the address in wp-config](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php).

Comment: website is listed correctly in https . and tried given solution but everything is the same without CSS.

Comment: Have you followed the advice [here](https://manovotny.com/fix-wordpress-admin-styles-not-loading) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323250/wordpress-wp-admin-css-not-loading/323255)?

Comment: results are same