# WordPress backend is loading as a list

Tags: css

So my backend is loading as just a bullet list, front end seems to be working fine. I'm not sure what made this happen. I've checked WordPress Integrity and it says it's fine. I've Reinstalled WordPress Core but it does nothing. Debugging shows nothing wrong. I've deactivated everything that does nothing to fix it. please help I can't seem to find any solutions for this problem as I can't find anyone else that has had this problem...
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217288) [2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323250) [3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163802l) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769141) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325159)

Comment: It looks like at least one of your CSS files for the backend isn't loading. Check the generated source and see which CSS file(s) give you a 404 (or 403, 400, 500, etc) status.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress wp-admin suddenly lost its style](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217288/wordpress-wp-admin-suddenly-lost-its-style)